# ArrayStoreException while deploying war containing wsdl

Tags: websphere, wsgen

I am facing the below issue while deploying my war in IBM WAS 8.5.5.3 server. Please have a look and give your suggestion of this error. I building the application I did'nt find any issue.

Facing this issue from sometime but still unable to resolve it.

```
[7/24/16 10:10:25:501 IST] 00000063 WASWSDLGenera E   WSWS7054E: The Web Services Description Language (WSDL) file could not be generated for the com.hex.rbm.erds.ws.endpoint.impl.EntitySearchServiceEndpoint Web service implementation class because of the following error: java.lang.ArrayStoreException
[7/24/16 10:10:25:507 IST] 00000063 WSModuleDescr E   WSWS7027E: JAX-WS Service Descriptions could not be correctly built because of the following error: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: WSWS7054E: The Web Services Description Language (WSDL) file could not be generated for the com.hex.rbm.erds.ws.endpoint.impl.EntitySearchServiceEndpoint Web service implementation class because of the following error: java.lang.ArrayStoreException
    at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.wsdl.WASWSDLGenerator.generateWsdl(WASWSDLGenerator.java:268)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.EndpointDescriptionImpl.generateWSDL(EndpointDescriptionImpl.java:2084)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.EndpointDescriptionImpl.<init>(EndpointDescriptionImpl.java:449)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.ServiceDescriptionImpl.<init>(ServiceDescriptionImpl.java:401)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.ServiceDescriptionImpl.<init>(ServiceDescriptionImpl.java:297)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.DescriptionFactoryImpl.createServiceDescriptionFromDBCMap(DescriptionFactoryImpl.java:277)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.DescriptionFactory.createServiceDescriptionFromDBCMap(DescriptionFactory.java:524)
    at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.desc.WSModuleDescriptorImpl.buildJAXWSServices(WSModuleDescriptorImpl.java:1345)
    at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.desc.WSModuleDescriptorImpl._containsJAXWSWebServices(WSModuleDescriptorImpl.java:519)
    at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.desc.WSModuleDescriptorImpl.containsJAXWSWebServices(WSModuleDescriptorImpl.java:494)
    at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.deploy.WSCacheWriter.writeModuleCache(WSCacheWriter.java:571)
    at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.deploy.WSCacheWriter.writeApplicationCache(WSCacheWriter.java:242)
    at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.deploy.WSCacheWriter.writeApplicationCache(WSCacheWriter.java:167)
    at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.deploy.PersistentStorageInstallSaveTask.performTask(PersistentStorageInstallSaveTask.java:196)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.sync.AppBinaryProcessor$ExpandApp.expand(AppBinaryProcessor.java:1711)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.sync.AppBinaryProcessor.postProcessSynchronousExt(AppBinaryProcessor.java:751)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.bla.sync.BLABinaryProcessor.postProcess(BLABinaryProcessor.java:599)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.bla.sync.BLABinaryProcessor.onChangeCompletion(BLABinaryProcessor.java:476)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.bla.sync.BinaryProcessorWrapper.onChangeCompletion(BinaryProcessorWrapper.java:109)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.repository.FileRepository.postNotify(FileRepository.java:1938)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.repository.FileRepository.update(FileRepository.java:1442)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.repository.client.LocalConfigRepositoryClient.update(LocalConfigRepositoryClient.java:189)
    at com.ibm.ws.sm.workspace.impl.WorkSpaceMasterRepositoryAdapter.update(WorkSpaceMasterRepositoryAdapter.java:665)
    at com.ibm.ws.sm.workspace.impl.RepositoryContextImpl.update(RepositoryContextImpl.java:1998)
    at com.ibm.ws.sm.workspace.impl.RepositoryContextImpl.synch(RepositoryContextImpl.java:1946)
    at com.ibm.ws.sm.workspace.impl.WorkSpaceImpl.synch(WorkSpaceImpl.java:549)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.action.SyncWorkSpaceAction.execute(SyncWorkSpaceAction.java:271)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(Unknown Source)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.setUpCommandAssistance(WSCUrlFilter.java:955)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.continueStoringTaskState(WSCUrlFilter.java:504)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.doFilter(WSCUrlFilter.java:325)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:960)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1064)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3878)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:981)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:461)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:528)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:314)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1864)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayStoreException
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:665)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:472)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:298)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation(AnnotationParser.java:234)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:81)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:64)
    at com.ibm.oti.reflect.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:63)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredAnnotations(Class.java:1879)
    at java.lang.Class.getAnnotations(Class.java:1836)
    at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Class.java:1816)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.xml.bind.v2.model.annotation.RuntimeInlineAnnotationReader.getClassAnnotation(RuntimeInlineAnnotationReader.java:106)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.xml.bind.v2.model.annotation.RuntimeInlineAnnotationReader.getClassAnnotation(RuntimeInlineAnnotationReader.java:57)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:329)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:483)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:319)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1178)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:194)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.xml.bind.api.JAXBRIContext.newInstance(JAXBRIContext.java:111)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.xml.ws.developer.JAXBContextFactory$1.createJAXBContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:109)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl$1.run(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:161)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl$1.run(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:154)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:327)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.createJAXBContext(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:153)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.postProcess(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:94)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.buildRuntimeModel(RuntimeModeler.java:258)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.ws.wscompile.WsgenTool.buildModel(WsgenTool.java:248)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.ws.wscompile.WsgenTool.run(WsgenTool.java:123)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.ws.util.WSToolsObjectFactoryImpl.wsgen(WSToolsObjectFactoryImpl.java:61)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.ws.spi.WSToolsObjectFactory.wsgen(WSToolsObjectFactory.java:107)
    at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.wsdl.WASWSDLGenerator.wsgen(WASWSDLGenerator.java:610)
    at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.wsdl.WASWSDLGenerator.generateWsdl(WASWSDLGenerator.java:245)
    ... 62 more
```

Comment: Since this is a java -> wsdl failure, it would probably help to post the key parts of your Java interface/impl with the JAX-WS annoations and also show any other relevant metadata.

Comment: I agree with Scott.  Also if you have your compiled code available in your development environment, you can run the command line tool (was_home)/java/bin/wsgen against your SEI and see if that one works.  If it throws an exception it might give you more information.

The one websphere uses internally is a little different, it's (profile_home)/bin/wsgen.bat/sh.  If you can get the wsdl and schema generated by one of these methods, then as a workaround, package it with your app and update your @WebService annotation to include the wsdllocation attribute.

Comment: The above end points worked when I add the jar validation.api 1.1.0.GA but previously I kept it in scope provided. Is there any way to keep the scope as provided and still it works?